# How to optimize a query on a view with a computed field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, query-optimization

In MongoDB I have a collection that holds documents with a timestamp. I also have a view on some of the documents (filtered by two fields) were these documents are aggregated (grouped by user and month). The view defines a compound index: it consists of `userId` and a `monthOfYear` (string with a month `YYYY-MM`). The view additionally defines only two fields: both are sums of some fields from the original collection.

Next I try to run queries on the view were I try to get last 13 entries of the view for a specific `userId`.

It appears that this query runs quite slowly even when there are no writing to the db (300ms for 50k documents in the original collection).

I don't understand what kind of indexes I should create to support my query. How can I optimize it?

Here is the view definition:

```
  {
    "name": "my_view",
    "type": "view",
    "options": {
      "viewOn": "my_collection",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "a": "val1",
            "b": "val2"
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {
              "userId": "$userId",
              "monthOfYear": {
                "$dateToString": {
                  "format": "%Y-%m",
                  "date": "$timestamp"
                }
              }
            },
            "total": {
              "$sum": "$val3"
            },
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            "_id.monthOfYear": -1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "info": {
      "readOnly": true
    }
  }
```

And the query:

```
 {
    "find": "my_view",
    "filter": {
      "_id.userId": "000000000aaaa",
      "_id.monthOfYear":
        {
          "$gte":
            "2019-01"
        }
    },
    "lsid": {
      "id": UUID("aaa-bbb")
    },
    "$db":
      "my-db"
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> MongoDB computes the view contents by executing the aggregation on-demand during read operations. MongoDB executes read operations on views as part of the underlying aggregation pipeline.
>   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/

So performing query for `my_view`, MongoDB fist performs aggregation on `my_collection`, then performs your query on returned results.

Try to create compound index `({a:1, b:1})` for `my_collection` to see if you performance improves, but `$group` decreases your query.

Other solution is [On-Demand Materialized Views](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/materialized-views/). You perform aggregation and use [$out or $merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#comparison-with-out) operators to store agregated data in `collection` (let's say `my_collection2`). Now, you create indexes for `my_collection2` and your queries will increase drastically.

**Note:** Each time you update `my_collection`, you need to update `my_collection2` data.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and report back

Comment: I already had compound indexes, both on `{a:1,b:1}` and `{userId:1,timestamp:1}`, the latter however is different from the computed index in the view - `timestamp` is converted to a string `YYYY-MM`. I think, I need to try saving the month explicitly in the document and then create index directly on it.